# Align y axis tick "outside" on highstock, so they are the same as on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to align the y axis tick "outside" on a highstock graph, so that it aligns with the gridline, rather than being "inside" and sat on top of the gridline. The documentation for highstock suggests that it should be placed "outside" by default, but looking at every example of a highstock graph, they always appear to be "inside".

`tickPosition: String. The position of the major tick marks relative to the axis line. Can be one of inside and outside. Defaults to "outside".`

Highchart example (what I want): http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Highstock example (what I get): http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Many thanks in advance.

**Update - a solution of sorts**

I came to the realisation that a `Highcharts.StockChart` is just a pre-configured version of `Highcharts.Chart` in the `highstock.js` file.

`HighCharts.Chart` has all the features of a `Highcharts.StockChart` - not just the features of a `Highcharts.Chart` in the `highcharts.js` file.

As a result, I have just used a `highstock.js` `Highcharts.Chart` with the configuration I require, and this places the yAxis labels in the correct position.

Answer (score 4):

You can use offset parameter for yAxis.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.offset

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4zwr/1/

```
 yAxis : {
        labels:{
            align:'right',
            x:-10
        },
        lineWidth : 1,
        offset : 30
    },
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't quite resolve the issue. Whilst this causes the numbers to be "pulled" away from the chart, they are not inline with the gridlines, and the border is the wrong side of the numbers. [Offset fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXd5W/1). [Highchart fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4zwr/)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4wrf63u/)): Add `labels: { align: 'left' }` to your yAxis options, like so:

```
yAxis: [{
    labels: {
        align: 'left'
    }
}]
```

This tells Highcharts to *align* the *left* end of the *labels* with the *y-axis*.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4wrf63u/